# How to align left in pandas when read txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a info.txt file it looks like this:

```
B 19960331 00100000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960430 00099100 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960531 00098500 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
```

And when I use pandas to read it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Petter\Desktop\info.txt')
df
```

and the output is:

```
    B 19960331 00100000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
                                                                     0  B 19960430 00099100 00000000000000 00000000000...
                                                                     1  B 19960531 00098500 00000000000000 00000000000...
```

The rows are far right from the column name,is there anyway I can make them like this:

```
    B 19960331 00100000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
0   B 19960430 00099100 00000000000000 00000000000...
1   B 19960531 00098500 00000000000000 00000000000...
```

I tried:

```
df.shift(periods=1, axis="columns")
```

but now work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to read the file with `pd.read_csv`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", sep=r"\s", header=None, dtype=str, engine="python")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   0         1         2               3               4               5         6               7               8               9
0  B  19960331  00100000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000
1  B  19960430  00099100  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000
2  B  19960531  00098500  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088484/how-to-automatically-fill-blank-column-with-none-in-pandas

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for your help,can you help with this question:Hi sir,can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090116/pandas-expected-10-fields-in-line-153-saw-11-how-to-add-one-more-column

Comment: Hi @Andrej friend,can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309137/how-to-cross-checking-2-pandas-dataframes-file-and-use-1-dataframes-value-as-a