# How to automatically fill blank column with None in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a info.txt file it looks like this:

```
B 19960331 00100000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960430 00099100 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960531 00098500 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19971000 20 31
```

And when I use pandas to read it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Petter\Desktop\info.txt'，sep=r"\s", header=None, dtype=str, engine="python")
df
```

the error is:

```
ParserError: Expected 10 fields in line 153, saw 14. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Is there any way to automatically fill the row that not the same column length, the output should looks like:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   B   19960331    00100000    00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000    00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000
1   B   19960430    00099100    00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000    00000000000000  00000000000000  00000000000000
2   B   19971000    20          31              None            None            None  None None None
```

I mean every blank column will be fill with None

Comment: I cannot reproduce, `pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=r"\s", header=None, dtype=str, engine="python")` produces expected output

Comment: Thank you for reply.The info.txt has been changed please check.Thanks!

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for your help,can you help with this question:Hi sir,can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090116/pandas-expected-10-fields-in-line-153-saw-11-how-to-add-one-more-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, and should(?) be the same as reading the file from disk:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

my_file = io.StringIO("""B 19960331 00100000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960430 00099100 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19960531 00098500 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000 00000000000000 00000000000000 00000000000000
B 19971000 20 31""")

df = pd.read_csv(my_file, sep="\s+", header=None)
```

output:

```
   0         1       2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  B  19960331  100000   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  B  19960430   99100   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  B  19960531   98500   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  B  19971000      20  31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hi sir,can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090116/pandas-expected-10-fields-in-line-153-saw-11-how-to-add-one-more-column

Comment: Hi @anon01 friend,can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309137/how-to-cross-checking-2-pandas-dataframes-file-and-use-1-dataframes-value-as-a