# Replace column values using a mapping-logic in pandas (problem with implementing a function)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe as follows. What I would like is to generate another column (`freq`) where the rows will have values according to this logic:

- If **Mode** column value starts with a digit `m`, then fill-in digit `n` in the **freq** column.

  ```sh
  - m: 1, n: 12
  - m: 6, n: 4
  - m: 7, n: 2
  - m: 8, n: 1
  ```

**DataFrame**

```
    Mode
0   602
1   603
2   700
3   100
4   100
5   100
6   802
7   100
8   100
9   100
10  100
```

Here is the logic that I tried implementing. But somehow it does not seem to work. Even if you could suggest some alternate solution, without using my code, that will work as well.

```
def check_mode(Mode):
    freq = ''
    if (Mode.str.startswith('8')).any(): 
        freq = 1
    elif (Mode.startswith("7")).all():  
        freq = 2
    elif (Mode.startswith("6")).any():  
        freq = 4
    elif (Mode.startswith("1")).any(): 
        freq = 12
    return freq

df['freq']=check_mode(df_ia['Mode'].values)
```

### Some observations

if I use:

```
if (Mode.str.startswith('8')).any():
```

I receive error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'
```

if I use:

```
if (Mode.startswith('8')).any():
```

I receive:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just take out `values`: `df["freq"] = check_mode(df_ia["Mode"])`

Comment: @William Are these always going to be three digit numbers: `801, 706, 100` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. **One liner**.

```py
df['freq'] = df.Mode.astype(str).str.get(0).replace({'8': 1, '7': 2, '6': 4, '1': 12})
```

Now let us unpack what it does:

```py
# You can run this cell and check the result as well

(df.Mode.astype(str) # convert the column "Mode" into str data type
   .str.get(0)       # get string based methods and access the get 
                     # method to get the 1st (`.get(0)`) digit
    # replace the digits with a dictionary that 
    # maps to their replacement values.
   .replace({'8': 1, '7': 2, '6': 4, '1': 12}))
```

### Code

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([602, 603, 700, 100, 100, 100, 802, 100, 100, 100, 100,], columns=['Mode'])
df['freq'] = df.Mode.astype(str).str.get(0).replace({'8': 1, '7': 2, '6': 4, '1': 12})
df

## Output
#     Mode  freq
# 0    602     4
# 1    603     4
# 2    700     2
# 3    100    12
# 4    100    12
# 5    100    12
# 6    802     1
# 7    100    12
# 8    100    12
# 9    100    12
# 10   100    12
```

Comment: @William Perhaps this is concise enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

print(df1)

```
    Mode
0    602
1    603
2    700
3    100
4    100
5    100
6    802
7    100
8    100
9    100
10   100



 c=[df1['Mode'].astype(str).str.startswith('8'),df1['Mode'].astype(str).str.startswith('7'),df1['Mode'].astype(str).str.startswith('6'),df1['Mode'].astype(str).str.startswith('1')]
 ch=[1,2,4,12]
 df1['newcol']=np.select(c, ch,0)
```

outcome

```
   Mode  newcol
0    602       4
1    603       4
2    700       2
3    100      12
4    100      12
5    100      12
6    802       1
7    100      12
8    100      12
9    100      12
10   100      12
```

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476193/how-to-merge-2-pandas-daataframes-base-on-multiple-conditions-faster

Answer (score 1):

Try with `np.select`

```
df=Mode
Mode = df.Mode.astype(str)
cond1 = Mode.str.startswith('8')
cond2 = Mode.str.startswith("7")
cond3 = Mode.str.startswith("6")
cond4 = Mode.str.startswith("1")
freq = [1,2,4,12]
df['new'] = np.select([cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4],freq)
df
   Mode  new
0   602    4
1   603    4
2   700    2
3   100   12
4   100   12
5   100   12
6   802    1
7   100   12
8   100   12
9   100   12
10  100   12
```

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476193/how-to-merge-2-pandas-daataframes-base-on-multiple-conditions-faster

Answer (score 0):

'startswith' is a pandas dataframe function/method. You are passing a numpy array to check_mode() method. This is the reason for getting below error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'
```

To avoid this issue send a pandas series as below

```
df['freq']=check_mode(df_ia['Mode'])
```

Note: Remember that Series object will not have 'startswith' due to which you would need to use str.startswith option and also need to have your data as strings for the same

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476193/how-to-merge-2-pandas-daataframes-base-on-multiple-conditions-faster